# Sending large file to gcloud worked on another internet connection but not mine

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

So I am doing this to send my 400 megabyte ai model to the cloud

```
model_file = pickle.dumps(model)

blob = bucket.blob("models/{user_id}.pickle")
blob.upload_from_string(model_file)
```

it takes a long time to process then i get three errors:

- ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2483)
- requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
- urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:

However when i was on another connection although still took a bit of time, it got sent.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. `blob.upload_from_string()` does not seem to activate multipart uploads for large strings. Setting the `chunk_size` attribute to, e.g. 8 MB solved my issue. Here's an example code:

```
blob = bucket.blob("models/{user_id}.pickle")
blob.chunk_size = 8 * 1024 * 1024
blob.upload_from_string(model_file)
```